# How to set node path for nodejs (Ubuntu)

Tags: postgresql, node.js

I'm trying to setup nodejs to access a postgres database. What I've done so far is the following (https://gist.github.com/579814):

```
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
mkdir ~/local
mkdir ~/node-latest-install
cd ~/node-latest-install
curl http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz | tar xz --strip-components=1
./configure --prefix=~/local
make install # ok, fine, this step probably takes more than 30 seconds...
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

then

```
git clone git://github.com/isaacs/npm.git
make
make install
```

so far, so good. However, when I try to install the postgres driver

```
npm install pg
```

I get the following:

> node-waf configure build || true

```
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for node path                   : not found 
Checking for node prefix                 : ok /usr/local 
Checking for program pg_config           : /usr/bin/pg_config 
'configure' finished successfully (0.066s)
Waf: Entering directory `/home/christian/node_modules/pg/build'
[1/2] cxx: src/binding.cc -> build/default/src/binding_1.o
../src/binding.cc:3:25: fatal error: node_events.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/christian/node_modules/pg/build'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): 
    {task: cxx binding.cc -> binding_1.o}
```

I've been looking around for setting the node path, although haven't found anything of help so far - probably also because I'm totally new to nodejs, so I'd be happy about any hint.

Comment: In newer versions of node.js, npm is included with node. You shouldn't need to do `curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh`.

Answer (score 14):

Now, you have NodeJS installed in your Ubuntu. You should set `/etc/environment` and load nodeJS path that can be executed by another users. For example:

```
NODE="/home/ubuntu/local/node"
NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules" 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:$NODE/bin:$NODE/lib/node_modules"
#PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```

Comment: Why that free hosting ad there :O

Answer (score 8):

Do this in bash:
echo `'export NODE_PATH=~/local/:~/local/node_modules' >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: thanks, that actually helped to to fix the node path, although the error of not finding the node_events.h still remained.

Comment: look at /home/christian/node_modules/pg/build is node_events.h anywhere. And look at other modules. Does the have it?

Comment: couldn't locate node_events.h anywhere, so it seems to be missing for some reason. It seems to me that node_events.h was removed from nodejs (https://github.com/joyent/node/commits/master/src/node_events.h), so is it possible, that the pg-driver still requires it?

Comment: I think that it your problem. Nodejs and its db modules uses events machine for asynchronous calls. So that way pg need it too.

Answer (score 0):

before things are fixed you must use node 0.5.1 (you can use gitk to revert the tree to this version)

```
Auteur: Ryan Dahl <ry@tinyclouds.org>  2011-07-19 10:46:38
Auteur du commit: Ryan Dahl <ry@tinyclouds.org>  2011-07-19 10:46:38
Parent: 0a3fc1d9c8becc32c63ae736ca2b3719a3d03c5b (Remove StatWatcher's dep on C++ EventEmitter)
Enfant:  061ce7b0ac370c8a5ae93d95ab7da171cbd488f0 (net_uv: Fix simple/test-http-expect-continue.js)
Branche: master, remotes/origin/master
Suit: v0.5.1
Précède: v0.5.2
Finally remove node::EventEmitter
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The issue was that I was specifying a old version of PG in my package.js
After I removed the old version dependancy I was able to install PG without issue.