# Install MySQL support for Node JS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to install MySQL support for NodeJS (v0.6.9) on Ubuntu. I'm issuing the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

I get no errors. I then install the module for Node:

```
sudo npm install -g db-mysql
```

Again. No errors. However, I do get what looks like a warning:

```
Checking for node path                   : not found
```

But the installation ends with:

```
'build' finished successfully (1.504s)
db-mysql@0.7.6 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/db-mysql
```

In my program source I now add:

```
var mysql = require("db-mysql");
```

But when I run this, I get the following error:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Cannot find module 'db-mysql'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:334:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:373:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/me/projects/node/test.js:4:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:444:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:462:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:482:10)
```

It obviously can't find the `db-mysql` module.

Comment: Is this helping ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076529/how-to-set-node-path-for-nodejs-ubuntu

Comment: I don't want to install from source if I can help it. I update Node through apt-get and I'd like the modules I use to follow a similar pattern.

Comment: Can you install `db-mysql` locally instead?  `npm install db-mysql` from your project directory.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js does not looking for modules in global modules folder (`/usr/local/lib`) by default.

You need to install your module locally by `npm install db-mysql`.

You can read more about module resolving strategy here: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders